# Auto trigger button javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
document.getElementById('auth-button').addEventListener('click', authorize);
```

When my page load I want to trigger that without clicking the button.

This is my view

[image: my View]

When authorized button clicked this is the output

[image]

I want to auto click that button when my page load.

Comment: `authorize();`.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: @melpomene - useless if the handler relies on `this`, or it's(the button's) place in the DOM tree. Not a helpful suggestion imho.

Comment: AyDee, I see that you are using vanilla javascript so I have posted my answer accordingly. Could you check if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Document ready in jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), try this..

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    authorize();
});
```

or this in javaScript..

```
window.onload = authorize;
```

**NOTE:** The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

Comment: OP has not mentioned that he is using jQuery, solution should be in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use addEventListener to the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    authButton.click();
}, false);
```

Full example:

https://jsfiddle.net/7q0gxehk/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could call the function `authorize()` on load of page using below code :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    authorize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use one of the following:**

```
<body onload="script();">
```

or

```
document.onload = function ...
```

or

```
window.onload = function ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register `authorize` as handler to be called when the page is fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(authorize);
```

This requires jQuery. The same can be achieved without jQuery this way:

```
window.addEventListener('load', authorize);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to tigger `authorize` function directly on page load using `window.onload` which is better than `document.onload`, see [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

```
window.onload = authorize;
```

However, if you are thinking about triggering click programmatically which is not suggested since it won't work properly across browsers e.g. Safari doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers offered thus far seem to take something into account - that the registered handler may in fact need to be aware of it's place in the DOM.

We could for instance, have a number of buttons that all call the same handler, with that handler manipulating the surrounding DOM. Simply calling `authorize` when the page loads will not be sufficient.

I've chosen to use DIVs instead of BUTTONs to demonstrate that the `.click()` method still works.

A far better way is to actually click the button, using javascript.

### #1 Not working

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function allByClass(clss){return document.getElementsByClassName(clss)}
// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need


window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 forEach(allByClass('mBtn'), addHandler);
 
 function addHandler(elem)
 {
  elem.addEventListener('click', authorize, false);
 }
 
 alert('hit a okay to call authorize');
 authorize();        // wont return from this call, since authorize relies on a valid 'this' value
}

function authorize(evt)
{
 this.classList.add('clicked');
 this.textContent = 'clicked';
}
```

```css
.mBtn
{
 border: solid 1px #555;
 border-radius: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.clicked
{
 color: #dddddd;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='mBtn'>Try me</div><div id='btn2' class='mBtn'>Or me</div><div class='mBtn'>Or even, me</div>
```

### #2 - Does work

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function allByClass(clss){return document.getElementsByClassName(clss)}
// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need


window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 forEach(allByClass('mBtn'), addHandler);
 
 function addHandler(elem)
 {
  elem.addEventListener('click', authorize, false);
 }
 
 alert('hit okay to click the 2nd button with javascript');
 byId('btn2').click();        // will return from this call, since authorize relies on a valid 'this' value, and the btn gives it one.
}

function authorize(evt)
{
 this.classList.add('clicked');
 this.textContent = 'clicked';
}
```

```css
.mBtn
{
 border: solid 1px #555;
 border-radius: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.clicked
{
 color: #dddddd;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='mBtn'>Try me</div><div id='btn2' class='mBtn'>Or me</div><div class='mBtn'>Or even, me</div>
```